# Nodejs doesn't redirect to https

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node server with express on top. Godaddy is the domain registrar that I use. 
If I try to connect with www.example.com doesn't work, only with https://www.example.com.
This is how the code looks like:

```
app.use(express_enforces_ssl());
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use (function (req, res, next) {
  if(req.secure){
    next();
  }else {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
});

var options = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server_cert_key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cfbe0f99da37dcae.crt')
};
https = require('https').createServer(options, app);
io = require('socket.io')(https);
```

However, if I 'ping www.example.com' the server is reached, but not in the browser.

The process is running on port 443 (dedicated port for secured connection).

I have made port forwarding from internal port 443 with output on port 80, this is how domain registrar works, only with port 80.

I don't know how can I fix it. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @S.D. is correct although if you want traffic to only use https then you can configure your web server to redirect http traffic to https

Comment: Yes, I want my users to use only secured connections. Sadly, @S.D method doesn't work.

Comment: Since you only want users to use secure connections you need to configure your server to redirect all traffic to https try following one of the following tutorials https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/best-way-to-configure-nginx-ssl-force-http-to-redirect-to-https-force-www-to-non-www-on-serverpilot-free-plan-by-using-nginx-configuration-file-only https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-redirect-from-http-to-https-on-apache2 depending on your web server the configuration will be different

Comment: Thanks. It is working with nginix

Answer (score 1):

DNS doesn't usually require ports info. Browser automatically assumes 80 for `http` scheme and 443 for `https` scheme.

The app code is only listening on 443. You need to add additional:

```
require('http').createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try normalizing the port before listen to it. 
In the code below, the port will be normalized according to the app settings. If none were found, it will be defaulted to port 80

```
function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) return val;
    if (port >= 0) return port;
    return false;
}

//port 443 if https:// is detected
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '80');

// for me, I imported ('http') instead of ('https') 
// but it also works on port 443
https.listen(port, function listening() {
    console.log('Listening on %d', server.address().port);
});
```